# Есть ли в списке только одна пара

Tags: python

```
def only_one_pair(numbers: list) -> bool:
    for i in range(len(numbers) - 1):
    if numbers[i] == numbers[i + 1]:
        return True
return False
```

Функция возвращает True, если в списке есть только одна пара (два элемента имеют одинаковое значение).
В других случаях:
нет элементов с одинаковым значением
существует более 2 элементов с одинаковым значением
есть несколько пар
возвращает Ложь.

```
assert only_one_pair([1, 2, 3]) is False
assert only_one_pair([1]) is False
assert only_one_pair([1, 2, 3, 1]) is True
assert only_one_pair([1, 2, 1, 3, 1]) is False
assert only_one_pair([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2]) is False
```

Pycharm выдает ошибку     assert only_one_pair([1, 2, 3, 1]) is True
AssertionError

Можете помочь разобраться, что не так?

Comment: Ошибка в том, что во всех представленных примерах будет False. Либо задание сформулировано неправильно, либо Вы не так его поняли.

Answer (score 1):

потому что вы сравниваете на равенство соседние элементы только, а в `[1, 2, 3, 1]` одинаковых соседних элементов нет и функция выдает `False`, хотя от нее ожидают `True`

правильный алгоритм мог быть таким, например:

1. получить уникальные элементы через `set`
2. подсчитать кол-во одинаковых элементов через `count`
3. подсчитать кол-во таких вариантов и если не 1 - выдать `False`